# Response.AddHeader is not working in Chrome and Safari Browsers

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using following code for downloading file and after downloading file its opens my site page, but its working only in Firefox browser. Its not working in other browsers.

```
Response.AddHeader("Refresh", "3; url=http://www.mysite.com/");
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=myfile.pdf");
Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("myfile.pdf"));
Response.End();
```

Comment: what is happening in other browsers?

Comment: In other browser file is download successfully but after downloading i want to open my website, its not opening its working in firefox properly but not in others.

Comment: Can you see any client side JS errors or is there any request made for the file and that is failing?

Comment: No nothing is there. I think Response.AddHeader is not working in other browsers

Answer (score 1):

You cannot reliably, cross-browser, push a file to the client and then redirect in one HTTP response.

Just create a landing page that shows what you want to show, and let that page (redirect to the) download.

Comment: Can you tell me please how to push a file to the client and redirect in one HTTP response.

Comment: You can't. Read the second line of my answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I think it's possible with AJAX. but technically not a single HttpResponse

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
Response.ClearContent();
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

Comment: This code is working only firefox browser, other browsers like chrome, safari is not working

Comment: Don't paste a block of code as a voodoo solution. Explain what "this code" does differently from OP's.

Comment: below code working in firefox not in other browsersResponse.ClearContent();
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

Comment: I am using this code for downloading files and it is working fine in every browser, that's way i pasted that as a solution

Answer (score 0):

I did stumbled upon this
'Use Double quotes so documents with comma in the filename is ok in Chrome
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=""" + myfile.Filnavn & "")

Maybe double quotes is necessary for Chrome

Comment: You should only post an answer if you're 100% sure, otherwise, just post a comment :)